# Provide function return from an if statement issues

Tags: if-statement, go, return

I'm having trouble returning a function's expected return statement from within an if statement in golang.

I have provided the code below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func random() string {
    var x = "return"

    if x == "return" {
        return x
    }
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println(random())
}
```

Shouldn't the main function print out the string value returned by the random function?All i get is

```
go.go:13: missing return at end of function
```

Does anybody have a clue how to make this happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to include a `return` at the end, even if it is never used, if the function returns a value:

http://play.golang.org/p/XFsPL2G15R

```
func random() string {
    var x = "return"

    if x == "return" {
        return x
    }
    return ""
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println(random())
}
```

Comment: Usually you would put a `panic("should never happen")` at the end. This is also allowed by the compiler and doubles as a sanity check.

Comment: This is one of the more idiotic behaviors of the Go compiler, together with the fact that unused variables and imports are errors and not warning. You need to do what the compiler wants you to do, not what you need to do, you know!

Answer (score 8):

In Go 1.1, you don't need to add return at the end of function all the time, but you need a *Terminating statement*, this code should work: 
http://play.golang.org/p/fNiijqNHbt

```
func random() string {
    var x = "return"

    if x == "return" {
        return x
    } else {
        return "else"
    }
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println(random())
}
```

For more infomation, see:

- http://golang.org/doc/go1.1#return
- http://golang.org/ref/spec#Terminating_statements