# Golang - Provide return after "if" statement when using framework

Tags: if-statement, go

It give error `missing return at end of function`. I've tried add `return nil`, `return ""`, `return c.String`, and several others but none works.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/hiteshmodha/goDevice"
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.Get("/", func(c *echo.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) *echo.HTTPError {

        deviceType := goDevice.GetType(r)

        if deviceType == "Mobile" {
            return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Mobile!")
        } else if deviceType == "Web" {
            return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Desktop!")
        } else if deviceType == "Tab" {
            return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Tablet!")
        }

    })

    e.Run(":4444")
}
```

This one quite different that other case such as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099144/go-provide-function-return-from-an-if-statement-issues).

Without framework, it works fine.

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/587tQh8urW

Comment: @MartinGallagher, I've tried that way before. It not works with error `panic: echo: unknown handler`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handler here is not what `echo.Get` is waiting for that's why you're getting this: `panic: echo: unknown handler`.
To get rid of this error change your handler to something like this: `func(c *echo.Context) error`
If you need to access the `http.Request` from inside the `handler` you can do it by using the `*echo.Context` which also contains a `*echo.Response`.

Working solution:

```
e.Get("/", func(c *echo.Context) error {
    deviceType := goDevice.GetType(c.Request())

    if deviceType == "Mobile" {
        return echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusOK, "Mobile!")
    } else if deviceType == "Web" {
        return echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusOK, "Desktop!")
    } else if deviceType == "Tab" {
        return echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusOK, "Tablet!")
    }

    return echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusNoContent, "Alien probe")
})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Got error `undefined: echo.NewHTTPError` - Is it typo or different Echo version? Another one, recent version Echo use `*echo.HTTPError` instead of `error`

Comment: I just `go get`'ed the last version of `Echo`. The version I used also returns a `*echo.HTTPError` which implement the `Error()` method from `error` interface. The handler seems to be able to return both `error` and `*echo.HTTPError`.

Comment: I just updated Echo to latest version and your solution works now. Thanks a lot